# Error al mostrar JSON con foreach PHP

Tags: php, json

Estoy listando los datos de un json y tengo este error:

> Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in

usuario.json

```
[
 {
    "id":1,
    "name":"sebastian",
    "email":"seba@mail.com",
    "pass":"1234",
    "esquema":{
        "base":27,
        "cu":4,
    },
    "menu":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "tipo":"desayuno",
            "cafe con leche":2,
            "tostadas":18,
            "mermelada":32,
            "huevo":12
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "tipo":"almuerzo",
            "tostadas":18,
            "mermelada":32
        },
        {
            "id":3,
            "tipo":"merienda",
            "tostadas":18,
            "queso crema":32,
            "huevo":12
        }
    ],
    "fecha":"2022-07-29"
 },
 {
    "id":2,
    "name":"mario",
    "email":"mario@mail.com",
    "pass":"12344",
    "esquema":{
        "base":27,
        "cu":4,
    },
    "menu":[
        {
            "id":3,
            "tipo":"desayuno",
            "cafe con leche":2,
            "tostadas":18,
            "mermelada":32,
            "huevo":12
        }
    ],
    "fecha":"2022-07-29"
 }
]
```

funciton.php

```
<?php

function getuser(){
    return json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/usuario.json'), true);
}

$users = getuser();
?>


<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
<?php echo $user['email']; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Ya he intentado agregar clave valor dentro del `foreach` pero tampoco tengo resultados.

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: El problema es un typo en el JSON y por eso PHP no lo puede parsear. Elimina las comas (`,`) de más en la línea **9** y la **43**. Puedes apoyarte de un [Json Validator](https://www.google.com/search?q=json+validator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que tenés comas al final de los valores.

Tal y como lo dice en la documentación de [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php):

```php
// las comas finales no están permitidas
$bad_json = '{ bar: "baz", }';
json_decode($bad_json); // null
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola deberias verificar que la variable $users, contenga un array, lo que esta diciendo es que esta variable, tiene como valor null